# Get HTTP status text in PHP or Laravel

Tags: php, http-headers, laravel-5.1, http-error

In Chrome inspector when I hit a 404 I see:

```
Request URL:http://myapp.dev/doesnotexist
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:192.X.X.X:80
```

So far I've only been able to get the numeric code, "404" by using `$exception->getStatusCode()`

Is there a way to get the text description of "Not Found" in PHP (or Laravel)?

Comment: Are you using cURL? It looks like `curl_error()` returns this information.

Comment: I have cURL installed but he error is not from a cURL request so I don't think that would work.

Comment: If Laravel doesn't provide an API to this, you may need to use cURL instead.

Comment: @Barmar I think OP is serving a web service, not consuming one.

Answer (score 1):

have you changed your **app/config/app.php** to:

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),
```

Comment: I need this to work in production (with debug off) because I want to display the error text to the end user for troubleshooting purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to display Custome 404 Error page, you can create 404.blade.php file in `views/errors` directory.